# iOS - Safe way to blur a UIImage

Tags: ios, objective-c, crash, uiimage, blur

In the past we had two different ways of blurring UIImages, and both led to crashes for our users. The first way crashes when the user puts the device into background (GPU error, not allowed to do anything in background).

The second one crashes with ESC_BAD_ACCESS errors.

What's a better (crash-safe) way to do it?

Version 1:

```
- (UIImage *)blurred:(float)inputRadius {

// create our blurred image
CIContext *context = [CIContext contextWithOptions:nil];
CIImage *inputImage = [CIImage imageWithCGImage:self.CGImage];
// setting up Gaussian Blur (we could use one of many filters offered by Core Image)
CIFilter *filter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIGaussianBlur"];
[filter setValue:inputImage forKey:kCIInputImageKey];
[filter setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:inputRadius] forKey:@"inputRadius"];
CIImage *result = [filter valueForKey:kCIOutputImageKey];

CGImageRef cgImage = [context createCGImage:result fromRect:[inputImage extent]];

UIImage *blurredImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgImage];

CFRelease(cgImage);
return blurredImage;
}
```

Version 2:

```
- (UIImage*)blurredImage:(CGFloat)blurRadius {
if (blurRadius < 0.0) {
    blurRadius = 0.0;
}

CGImageRef img = self.CGImage;
CGFloat inputImageScale = self.scale;

vImage_Buffer inBuffer, outBuffer;
vImage_Error error;

void *pixelBuffer;

CGDataProviderRef inProvider = CGImageGetDataProvider(img);
CFDataRef inBitmapData = CGDataProviderCopyData(inProvider);

inBuffer.width = CGImageGetWidth(img);
inBuffer.height = CGImageGetHeight(img);
inBuffer.rowBytes = CGImageGetBytesPerRow(img);

inBuffer.data = (void*)CFDataGetBytePtr(inBitmapData);

pixelBuffer = malloc(CGImageGetBytesPerRow(img) * CGImageGetHeight(img));

outBuffer.data = pixelBuffer;
outBuffer.width = CGImageGetWidth(img);
outBuffer.height = CGImageGetHeight(img);
outBuffer.rowBytes = CGImageGetBytesPerRow(img);

CGFloat inputRadius = blurRadius * inputImageScale;
if (inputRadius - 2. < __FLT_EPSILON__)
    inputRadius = 2.;
uint32_t radius = floor((inputRadius * 3. * sqrt(2 * M_PI) / 4 + 0.5) / 2);

radius |= 1; // force radius to be odd so that the three box-blur methodology works.

// line of crash
error = vImageBoxConvolve_ARGB8888(&inBuffer, &outBuffer, NULL, 0, 0, radius, radius, NULL, kvImageEdgeExtend);

if (!error) {
    error = vImageBoxConvolve_ARGB8888(&outBuffer, &inBuffer, NULL, 0, 0, radius, radius, NULL, kvImageEdgeExtend);
}

if (error) {
    return self;
}

CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();

CGContextRef ctx = CGBitmapContextCreate(outBuffer.data,
                                         outBuffer.width,
                                         outBuffer.height,
                                         8,
                                         outBuffer.rowBytes,
                                         colorSpace,
                                         (CGBitmapInfo)kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipLast);

CGImageRef imageRef = CGBitmapContextCreateImage (ctx);

UIImage *returnImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];

CGContextRelease(ctx);
CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);

free(pixelBuffer);
CFRelease(inBitmapData);

CGImageRelease(imageRef);

return returnImage;
}
```

Comment: Can you clarify: where does the crash happen? Using Core Image is definitely the right way to approach the problem.

Comment: The version 1 crashes because you can't make GPU operation while you app is in background, but you can ask CIContext to be created for CPU elaboration by setting the option kCIContextUseSoftwareRenderer to YES, but it would be very slow. The version 2 is a  lot faster than common CPU elaboration. remember that from iOS8 you can use UIVisualEffect if you need to perform blur in real time.

Comment: Thanks for the fast answers, I marked the line of crash in the second approach with a comment. I can't use iOS 8 features, have to support iOS 7, actually we're still supporting iOS 6, but 7 is the most important.

Comment: @keyboard the second is part of a sample code from apple, are you using the original version? https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/UIImageEffects/Listings/ReadMe_txt.html what is the size of your images?

Comment: I wasn't aware, I found the second part somewhere on Stackoverflow when I was searching for a new way to do it. The images can be fairly large, up to full screen. Why are you asking?